# Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'YoutubeAPI'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere

So I have created a simple API and it is working fine. Now the thing is I want to host my API in any hosting website, so I found PythonAnywhere.
Now I have installed Django, DRF in the PythonAnywhere bash console
and I made project (API) and startapp (YoutubeAPI) and added `rest_framework` in `settings.py` file and all things done.

Now I added my exact same data of `models.py`, `serializer.py`, `views.py` and `urls.py` and all in PythonAnywhere project files.

Now when I run `manage.py` I'm getting `module not found 'YoutubeAPI'`.

Below is the tree structure attachment

[image]

Comment: My advice to you is deploy your apps in the future on **heroku** because **pythonanywhere** provides you only with a **three months** for free as i know when i had a try with it before.

Comment: It's not true, about three months.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need:

- Python 2.7 or Python 3.5+
- The pip package management tool
- The Google APIs Client Library for Python:

  ```
  pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
  ```
- The google-auth-oauthlib and google-auth-httplib2 libraries for user authorization:

  ```
  pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2
  ```

Try to check this before you start: [Click Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python)

Answer (score 0):

There are different versions of python installed on PythonAnywhere. Each has its own set of installed modules. See https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/

You need to make sure that you are running your web app in the same version of python as your models were installed. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/

Also, you may create a virtual environment and install your modules there. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/VirtualenvsExplained and https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Virtualenvs/